# Angular Material Table Cell :after element

Tags: angular, css, angular-material, mat-table

I have no idea what this is or how more importantly how to access it.
 I am hoping someone has come by this problem before.

**Scenario :**

I am working on making a responsive table and it seems like there is a "Phantom Cell" at the end

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the selector

```
  mat-footer-row::after, mat-header-row::after, mat-row::after {
    min-height: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mat-footer-row::after, mat-header-row::after, mat-row::after {
    display: block !important;
    min-height: 0!important;
  }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.